# Is this a correct choice for partition and row key in Azure table?

Tags: azure, database-design

I have a table that stores the online status of a user.

```
columns(userid, IsOnline,date)
```

If the user is online, the Isonline bool flag is true, if it goes offline, the IsOnline bool is false. This way I can see between which and which time the user was online.

Would it be fine choosing partitionKey: userId,
Rowkey: the date and time of the event

?

The user can not go on and off at the same time, so rowkey should be unique. I like about this that it keeps all data for a user on the same partition. Also does choosing the date as rowId make sorting more efficient?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UserId is a good strategy for the PartitionKey

With respect to RowKey, I would suggest using "DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - dateOfEvent.Ticks" formatted to max number of digits.

This will make your RowKey always be in the descending order and thus allow you to pick the latest status of the user without getting data from all of he partition

Comment: I just came across this post, and I'm interested in this suggestion. Can you elaborate about why having data in descending order is beneficial in this case? Wouldn't the date / time of the event still be in descending order?

Comment: The way Azure Table Storage works is that you cannot have it change sorting when retrieving data.  It is stored in ascending PK/RK way. First row to be retrieved is the smallest RK for a given PK.  If one wants to find out the latest status of a user and RK is timestamp stored in ASC order, the first row will be the earliest status and thus the consumer of the data will have to retrieve all of the rows before finding out latest status.  Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds reasonable to me.  This groups all of a given user's actions together in a single partition.  Each action is then delineated by an individual row with the Timestamp for the key.

You might want to keep in mind that every row in Azure Table Storage has a Timestamp column that is populated automatically on create/update.  You could consider using this column for your Timestamp but searching/sorting will be slow since it is part of the tertiary data set associated with a Table Storage row.